# Titration of H+ by iodometry

Tags: titration

Propose a titration protocol for a hydrochloric acid solution of approximate concentration 0.1M using the solutions and materials available.

**Solutions**:
-$V_0$ = 20mL of hydrochloric acid solution of unknown concentration.
-Solution of $\ce{KIO3}$ at $C_1$=0.1 mol/L
-solution of $\ce{KI}$ at $C_1$=0.1 mol/L
-$\ce{Na2S2O3^2-}$ solution at $C_2$ = 0.01 mol/L
-concentrated sulphuric acid

**Equipment**: - common glassware
-no pH meter, conductivity meter or colour indicators

**Data** :
-Experiment 1: a solution of $\ce{I2}$ to which a few drops of soda are added becomes colourless
-Experiment 2: a solution of iodate and iodide ions to which a few drops of sulphuric acid are added becomes brownish-orange.

-Standard redox potential = E°($\ce{S4O6^{2-}}$/$\ce{S2O3^{2-}}$)=0.08V
-E-pH diagram of iodine plotted for the species: $\ce{I2}$, $\ce{IO3^-}$, $\ce{I^-}$

[image]

My ideas: Add excess $\ce{I^-}$ and excess $\ce{IO3^-}$ to the hydrochloric acid soluton. We then have $5\ce{I^- }+ \ce{IO3^-} + \ce{6H^+} = 3\ce{I2}+ 3\ce{H2O}$. The constant for this reaction can be calculated by retrieving the associated thermodynamic constants from the diagram. The $\ce{I2}$ formed is then titrated with $\ce{S2O3^{2-}}$. The $\ce{H^+}$ concentration in the initial state can be deduced from this. However, I think that this method is not good because the first reaction is largely total and the colorimetric titration is not precise enough to determine the correct values.

Is there another method that is simpler or more accurate?

Comment: Hello, welcome; please do check out [FAQ: How can I format math/chemistry expressions on Chemistry Stack Exchange?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/16683) — in particular the `mhchem` sections: the chemical formulae and equations in your post should be typed as `$\ce{Na2S2O3}$`, i.e. $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ or `\ce{S2O3^2-}` i.e. $\ce{S2O3^2-}$.

Comment: I think it is just an academic exercise and all your teacher wanted is that you write a balanced equation showing the reaction of iodate, iodide and HCl. Iodometry is/was never meant to determine hydrogen ion concentration. It just like asking you to re-invent a triangular wheel.

Comment: @M.Farooq so the method I used is theorically right but experimentally false ?

Comment: @Julien, Yes sort of. Good for paper work but no one will do it in reality. So your proposed solution is perhaps the only solution to satisfy your instructor.

Comment: Iodate-iodide can be used to standardize STRONG acids because the reaction is very pH dependent and stops abruptly at ~pH 7.  I can't find a reference. It was in my Quant analysis Text which was lost when my company moved the lab. Simply add a slight excess of an iodate-iodide solution to a measured amount of acid and titrate the iodine with thiosulfate. No need to weigh anything if you buy standard thiosulfate but iodate can also be used as a primary standard.